How can I configure docker container permissions that persist without a start script?
We have applications running in docker containers via compose. I mounted the config files and log folders via compose volumes; the applications don't have permissions for these folders, even if I set the permissions on the host machine to correspond to the UID or GID of the user the container uses. When I check the permissions of those folders from within the container, they're always owned by nobody and I can't seem to figure out how to control these permissions in docker or have the permissions passed from the host to docker. Exec'ing into the container to update permissions is something I'd rather avoid for security reasons.
I have tried the solutions stated docker volume custom mount point -- to mount the volume like the below:
    name: test-deux
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/opt/dev/fleet-forge/services/srv'

however, it doesn't affect where it's actually mounted:
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2024-06-13T11:00:39-05:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "fleet-forge",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.26.1",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "test-deux"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/civpldocker-raid/docker/820896.820896/volumes/test-deux/_data",
        "Name": "test-deux",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/opt/dev/fleet-forge/services/srv",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]

I've also tried appending :rw to the volume location to no effect.
EDIT:
Adding some simple reproducible examples, as resquested by Hans Kilian.
MountingPoint not updated by driver_opts > device: :
services:

  utility:
    container_name: alpine-test
    image: alpine:latest
    volumes:
      - test:/test
    command: sleep infinity

volumes:
  test:
    name: test
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/opt/dev/fleet-forge/services/test'

when deploying this on my machine with docker compose up, it creates the volume; when I inspect the volume:
$ docker inspect test
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2024-06-14T08:21:49-05:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "test-mount",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.26.1",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "test"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/civpldocker-raid/docker/820896.820896/volumes/test/_data",
        "Name": "test",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/opt/dev/fleet-forge/services/test",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]

$ ls /opt/dev/fleet-forge/services/test
total 4
drwxr-sr-x.  2 <user> <grp>   40 Jun 14 08:09 .
drwxrwsr-x. 32 <user> <grp> 4096 Jun 14 08:09 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 <user> <grp>    0 Jun 14 08:09 testfile1
-rw-r--r--.  1 <user> <grp>    0 Jun 14 08:09 testfile2

:rw not giving the container RW permissions for a bind mount:
$ cat docker-compose.yml
services:

  utility:
    container_name: alpine-test
    image: alpine:latest
    volumes:
      - /opt/dev/fleet-forge/services/test:/test:rw
    command: sleep infinity

$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container alpine-test  Started                     

$ dockerpsm
CONTAINER ID   NAMES                 STATUS
758c582c2b91   alpine-test           Up 35 seconds

$ docker exec -it 758c582c2b91 /bin/sh
/ # ls -alt
total 80
drwx------    1 root     root          4096 Jun 14 13:28 root
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 14 13:27 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 14 13:27 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Jun 14 13:27 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           340 Jun 14 13:27 dev
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 14 13:27 etc
dr-xr-xr-x 1251 nobody   nobody           0 Jun 14 13:27 proc
drwxr-sr-x    2 nobody   nobody          40 Jun 14 13:09 test
...

/ # touch test/testfile3
touch: test/testfile3: Permission denied

Simple bind mounting (I use this to refer to the second example--I believe that's the proper term) does exactly what I want, sans permissions. The folder is mounted and accessible inside the container, other than the permissions not replicating from the host to the container or permissions to the folders being able to be added, from what I've tried thus far.
Edit:
Here are the permissions on the local drive, which is being mounted in option 2:
$ pwd
/opt/dev/fleet-forge/services/test
$ ls -alt
total 4
drwxr-sr-x.  2 pstewart dev   40 Jun 14 08:09 .
drwxrwsr-x. 32 pstewart dev 4096 Jun 14 08:09 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 pstewart dev    0 Jun 14 08:09 testfile1
-rw-r--r--.  1 pstewart dev    0 Jun 14 08:09 testfile2

I'm wondering if there's some docker setting I don't have set to allow this to work as expected?

Would it be possible for you to expand your post to have a reproducible example? Then I'll be happy to take a look. As it is, your post isn't concrete enough for me to be able to pinpoint the cause.

Sure, I'm updating the post to include these tests.

I've tried to replicate your issue using the last compose file in your post and I can't. I've created /opt/dev/fleet-forge/services/test and set the attributes to match yours. Inside the container, /test is owned by my UID instead of nobody as you have. And I can create a file in the directory. I can't see the attributes on the entire host path in your post. So maybe there's something weird there? Is the host directory on a local drive or is it a mounted network drive or something? That might cause issues.

@HansKilian thanks, I edited to add show the permissions on the local drive that I'm using as the bind mount. pstewart is my personal user, not tied to the container; dev is the group, which is the same GID as the container's group and the container's UID is in the group on the host system as well.
